# How do I request JSON data from a OData service operation using OData4J?

Tags: json, odata, odata4j

I am trying to query a WCF OData service from Java using the odata4j library. If I query a entity using ATOM format, everything is OK. If I switch to JSON, Java throws following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: EdmEntitySet GetStatesViewData?gac=0 not found
    at org.core4j.ReadOnlyIterator.hasNext(ReadOnlyIterator.java:49)
    at org.core4j.Enumerable$FuncIterator.hasNext(Enumerable.java:487)
    at org.core4j.Enumerable$FuncIterator.hasNext(Enumerable.java:487)
    at ... Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: EdmEntitySet GetStatesViewData?gac=0 not found at org.odata4j.edm.EdmDataServices.getEdmEntitySet(EdmDataServices.java:40)
at org.odata4j.internal.EdmDataServicesDecorator.getEdmEntitySet(EdmDataServicesDecorator.java:31)
at org.odata4j.format.json.JsonFeedFormatParser.parse(JsonFeedFormatParser.java:99)
at org.odata4j.format.json.JsonFeedFormatParser.parse(JsonFeedFormatParser.java:21)
at org.odata4j.consumer.OQueryRequestImpl$EntryIterator.advance(OQueryRequestImpl.java:192)
at org.core4j.ReadOnlyIterator.hasNext(ReadOnlyIterator.java:47)
... 10 more
```

The following code produced this exception:ODataConsumer odc =

```
ODataConsumer.create(FormatType.JSON, "http://localhost:6000/");
        Iterator<OEntity> iterator = odc.getEntities("GetStatesViewData?gac=0").execute();
for(OEntity entity: entities)
{
..
}
```

OData4j is not able to find an entity "GetStatesViewData?gac=0", but such a property does not exist. What exists is a service operation "GetStatesViewData" which accepts a parameter "gac". Is it possible to call a service operation with parameters using OData4j?

If I use Fiddler or some other web debugger, send a HTTP request with a "accept: application/json" header to this OData Service, I normally get the JSON feed. So there is something wrong either in OData4j or in my code, the OData server seems to be OK.

Comment: It behaves the same If I query an entity and not a service method, so it is not a problem of missing support for service methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently (as of version 0.5) - you can use [callFunction](http://odata4j.googlecode.com/hg-history/0.5/odata4j-core/doc/javadoc/org/odata4j/consumer/ODataConsumer.html#callFunction%28java.lang.String%29) to call a service operation.

See [FunctionTest.java on the odata4j Github repo](https://github.com/odata4j/odata4j/blob/092862b626eca1443b8fe732ac44ee17837aa397/odata4j-fit/src/test/java/org/odata4j/test/integration/producer/jpa/northwind/FunctionTest.java) for an example.

Hope that helps,

- john

Comment: Great, the version 0.5 is finally released! What a great news:) Thanks, John.